# The equation $x^y = y^x$.

Tags: exponential-function

The following equation has been of interest for a long time. I'm bringing this to your attention again:

$$x^y = y^x$$

How do you attack to find all real and imaginary solutions for this equation? or

What is the nicest solution that you have seen?

Comment: Start by taking logs and graphing the function $f(x)=\dfrac{\log x}x$.

Comment: x=y. but its trivial. x^y < y^x to wolfram alpha shows how it really works.

Comment: if your $x,y$ are complex and not real, there is no principal value for either expression and you have a mess. If you demand at least one of them real and positive you get something sensible.

Comment: As far as I know, the only non complex pair not on y=x is (2,4). I don't have a proof...

Comment: Make titles more informative, please.

Answer (score 4):

The standard way I have seen
to solve $x^y = y^x$
is to define
$\frac{y}{x} = r$.

Then $y = xr$,
so
$x^{xr} = (xr)^x$
or
$x^r = xr$
or
$x^{r-1} = r$
or
$x = r^{1/(r-1)}$.

From this,
$y 
=xr
= r^{1+1/(r-1)}
= r^{r/(r-1)}
$.

Any value you put in for $r$
(except $r=1$)
gives you $x$ and $y$
that satisfy $x^y = y^x$,
and conversely.

For example,
if you start with
$r = i$,
$\frac{1}{r-1}
=\frac{1}{i-1}
=\frac{-i-1}{(-i-1)(i-1)}
=\frac{-i-1}{2}
$
and
$\frac{r}{r-1}
=\frac{i}{i-1}
=\frac{i(-i-1)}{(-i-1)(i-1)}
=\frac{1-i}{2}
$.
Then
$x = 
i^{(-i-1)/2}
$
and
$y
=i^{(1-i)/2}
$.
(I'll let you work the
standard form for $x$ and $y$.)

Answer (score 0):

Allowing the Lambert W function,

$$y=e^{W_k\left(\frac{-\ln(x)}{x}\right)}$$

where $k$ is the branch.  From graphing, you can see that only two branches, $k=0,-1$, (I think) produce real values for $x,y$.  All other branches will produce complex values.

Answer (score -3):

y=-x*W(-(ln(x)/x)/ln(x)

W(x) is the Lambert W function