# Finiteness of the set of pairs of distinct natural numbers whose ratio is equal the ratio of their logarithms?

Tags: number-theory

This is being asked in the context of finding pairs of numbers that make the expression $a^b$ invariant to swapping exponent and base.

Let's say I have two *distinct* natural numbers $X,Y$, where:

$$\frac{X}{Y} = \frac{\ln(X)}{\ln(Y)}$$

Can this happen for only finitely many distinct $X,Y \in \mathbb{N}$

Here's a specific example I found:

$$(2,4): \ln(2)/\ln(4)=1/2$$

Comment: Solved repeatedly on MSE as integer solutions of $x^y=y^x$. Hint: Where is $\frac{\ln t}{t}$ increasing, decreasing?  The answer is yes, very finite.

Comment: May see [link 1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1211477/graph-of-the-function-xy-yx-and-e-eulers-number) and [link 2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476033/the-equation-xy-yx)

Comment: @NgChungTak thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your equation as $\frac {\ln X}X=\frac {\ln Y}Y$ Logs are **tiny** compared to the number once the number gets at all large, so you need one of $X,Y$ to be less than $e$.  There aren't many naturals to choose from.  You can formalize this with derivatives of $\frac {\ln x}x$

Comment: Thanks for the good intuition. I also found a nice paper on it from MAA some time ago: http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Sved50816668.pdf.

Comment: So, I'm concluding that $x^{y^z} = y^{z^x} = z^{x^y}$ doesn't have non-trivial integer solutions